# Android rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas, shapes

Hello guys i have a problem with a rect. I want to disappear a rect so that intersect method cant find the specific rect when other rectangles intersects it.Sorry if the solution is obvious , i am new to programming.

Comment: its in api demos can you go there and check it.

Comment: can you please post the link so i can see.I cant find it

Comment: you can also check in emulator api demo graphics->regions.

Answer (score 0):

//check the the API demos Graphics->Regions

[Code Link:](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Regions.html)

[image]

Comment: not exactly , i wanted to make the rectangle invisible to intersection with other rectangles, i code i typed rect.setEmpty but it was not the solution as i see cause it set the rect on position 0,0,0,0 and not invisible as i thought , any ideas?